# Exception in plugin Android Support when I start a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have upgraded my android studio to 3.3.1 version. I cannot create new projects. 
When I start a new project i get the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO4P7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have a Kotlin plugin installed. Sounds like it's a known issue in Android Studio: https://issuetracker.google.com/122892909

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you don't have `Kotlin` plugin installed. When Android Studio is open, click **Configure**(bottom-right corner)>**SDK Manager**>**Search for Kotlin**.

In the Kotlin Tab, install the Kotlin plugin or update the current one if you have already installed. This would solve the error.
As @Izabela said, it's already a known issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/122892909